# Segmentation fault in strtok_r on stack string

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, stack, strtok

I'm getting a segmentation fault in `strtok_r` in the following piece of code and I've spent a few hours trying to figure out why. Answers on other pages say you can't modify a string literal, but (as far as I know) I'm not.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char req[256];
    //char* req = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(req, "hello\r\nversion 1.0\r\n\r\n");
    char** lineSavePtr;
    char* line = strtok_r(req, "\r\n", lineSavePtr);
}
```

If I switch the declaration of `req` to the dynamic one, it works. It also works if I use `strtok` instead of `strtok_r`, so I'm guessing it might have something to do with `lineSavePtr`?

Thanks a lot for any answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok_r):

> The `saveptr` argument is a pointer to a `char *` variable that is used internally by s`trtok_r()` in order to maintain context between successive calls that parse the same string.

You've provided an uninitialized pointer, not a pointer to a `char *` variable. When it tries to dereference the pointer, undefined behavior occurs.

Declare the variable as `char *`, and pass a pointer to the variable using `&`.

```
int main() {
    char req[256];
    //char* req = malloc(256 * sizeof(char));
    strcpy(req, "hello\r\nversion 1.0\r\n\r\n");
    char* lineSavePtr;
    char* line = strtok_r(req, "\r\n", &lineSavePtr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! Do you perhaps know why it worked if I allocated `req` dynamically?

Comment: Anything can happen when you cause undefined behavior, including the appearance of working correctly.